# How is "beta" relevant to long-term ETF investors?

Tags: investing, etf, index-fund, volatility, beta

A portion of my investment portfolio is in index-tracking ETFs. On the whole, my ETF portfolio is diversified across many countries and industries. I intend to hold these ETFs for 20-40 years. I noticed that some financial data providers give a "beta" statistic for my ETFs. Given my long-term investment horizon, should I care about the "beta" of my ETFs? What is the relevance of the "beta" volatility measure in the context of a diversified index-tracking ETF portfolio where the positions are held for decades?

Comment: I believe, there are various betas in existance. Soem betas are believed to guarantee higher growth than the average. This serves you as a long term investor.

Answer (score 1):

For equities and equity ETFs, Betas typically means "sensitivity to market returns". Meaning that if you have a Beta of 1.5, when the market goes up 2% one day, then the ETF *on average* will go up 3%. It's not an *exact* result, meaning it's not a certainty, but it's an average calculated from the history of price movements of the ETF compared to the movements to the market overall.

In more practical terms, a higher beta ETF is *more risky* than the market on average, and thus should expect higher returns. And vice-versa; a low-beta ETF is "safer" than the market on average. You can also have *zero* beta (the ETF movement is not correlated to the market at all) and *negative* beta, meaning the ETF tends to move *against* the market. Those are typically only found in ETFs that use derivatives to speculate on other factors than market price (e.g. "beta-neutral" or "inverse" funds).